# Maxime : "Tout extrême nuit"

Tags: proverbes

J'ai souvent entendu dire "tout extrême nuit", mais pour étayer un aparté sur [une question sur ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/475253/help-me-to-find-a-proverb-about-average-being-better/475280#475280) j'ai voulu trouver des références sur cette maxime. Impossible ! J'ai cru me souvenir d'un "Fuyez les extrêmes, car...", sortant d'un quelconque recueil de poèmes moralisateurs, mais là encore je ne trouve rien.

Est-ce que quelqu'un aurait des références sur ces maximes, ou des similaires ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un relevé de [citations célèbres](https://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/citation/extreme/1/0.php) qui impliquent la considération de certains extrêmes tends à confirmer la maxime « Tout extême nuit » bien que ce ne soit qu'une tendance et il existe des extrêmes reconnus comme souhaitables.

En fait de maxime reconnue je ne peux trouver que quelque chose de très proche mais pas exactement équivalent; c'est une forme acceptable de la locution latine « **Est modus in rebus** », laquelle peut se traduire par « l'excès en tout est un défaut » ou sans ambiguïté « **Dans tout l'excès est un défaut** »; on trouve une confirmation de l'interprétation dans cette [source](https://www.latin-is-simple.com/en/vocabulary/phrase/549/).

Suit ci-dessous une liste de citations auxquelles je réfère plus haut.

L'extrême en tout est un défaut, dit calmement Nathalie.
Léon Tolstoï Anna Karénine (1873-1877) de Léon Tolstoï

L'extrême humilité est une des voies de l'orgueil.
Jean-Christophe Rufin Immortelle Randonnée : Compostelle malgré moi (2013) de Jean-Christophe Rufin

J'insiste donc, et je dis : c'est l'extrême sensibilité qui fait les acteurs médiocres ; c'est la sensibilité médiocre qui fait la multitude des mauvais acteurs ; et c'est le manque absolu de sensibilité qui prépare les acteurs sublimes.

L'extrême pureté peut contempler le pur et l'impur ; l'impureté ne peut ni l'un ni l'autre : le premier lui fait peur, le second l'absorbe.
Simone Weil La Pesanteur et la Grâce (1947) de Simone Weil

Lorsqu'on sent le monde sur le point de chavirer, quelque chose dérègle : les hommes sombrent soit dans l'extrême dévotion soit dans l'extrême débauche.
Amin Maalouf Le Périple de Baldassare (2000) de Amin Maalouf

L'extrême logique, c'est peut-être ce qu'on nomme la folie!
Boileau-Narcejac Sueurs froides (1958) de Boileau-Narcejac

L'intimité ne se discerne pas de l'extrême franchise. C'est l'indécence même.
Pascal Quignard Vie secrète (1998) de Pascal Quignard

Ne serrez qu'avec une extrême prudence la main inconnue qui presse la vôtre avec une extrême cordialité.
Félix Guillaume Marie Bogaerts Pensées et Maximes de Félix Guillaume Marie Bogaerts

L'extrême richesse et l'extrême pauvreté ont en commun de détruire les Etats et les hommes.
Robert Sabatier Le livre de la déraison souriante (1991) de Robert Sabatier

L'extrême défiance n'est pas moins nuisible que son contraire; la plupart des hommes deviennent inutiles à celui qui ne veut pas risquer d'être trompé.
Luc de Clapiers, marquis de Vauvenargues Réflexions et Maximes (1746) de Luc de Clapiers, marquis de Vauvenargues

Rien ne donne plus de force aux lois que la subordination extrême des citoyens aux magistrats.
Charles de Secondat, baron de Montesquieu De l'esprit des lois (1748) de Charles de Secondat, baron de Montesquieu

C'est ainsi, qu'un amant, dont l'ardeur est extrême, 
 Aime jusqu'aux défauts des personnes qu'il aime.
Jean-Baptiste Poquelin, dit Molière Le Misanthrope (1666), II, 4, Eliante de Jean-Baptiste Poquelin, dit Molière

Les crimes de l'extrême civilisation sont certainement plus atroces que ceux de l'extrême barbarie par le fait de leur raffinement, de la corruption qu'ils supposent, et de leur degré supérieur d'intellectualité.
Jules Amédée Barbey d'Aurevilly Les Diaboliques (1874), La vengeance d'une femme de Jules Amédée Barbey d'Aurevilly

Quelle est la grande action qui ne soit pas un extrême au moment où on l'entreprend?
Henri Beyle, dit Stendhal Le Rouge et le Noir (1830) de Henri Beyle, dit Stendhal

L'extrême netteté, la clarté, et la certitude ne s'acquièrent qu'au prix d'un immense sacrifice: la perte de la vue d'ensemble. 
Albert Einstein de Albert Einstein

On ne s'élève que par de grandes vertus ou par de grands crimes, par des talents supérieurs ou par une stupidité avérée, par une extrême hauteur ou par une extrême bassesse: toujours par les extrêmes.
Laurent Angliviel de La Beaumelle Mes pensées ou Le qu'en dira-t-on (1752), CLVIII de Laurent Angliviel de La Beaumelle

L'extrême plaisir que nous prenons à parler de nous-mêmes nous doit faire craindre de n'en donner guère à ceux qui nous écoutent.
François, duc de La Rochefoucauld Réflexions ou Sentences et Maximes morales (1664), 314 de François, duc de La Rochefoucauld

L'extrême civilisation engendre l'extrême barbarie.
Pierre Drieu la Rochelle Les Chiens de paille de Pierre Drieu la Rochelle

A grande offrande, grande réflexion, et à politesse extrême, méfiance extrême!
Mateo Alemán Guzmán de Alfarache de Mateo Alemán

Comment: J'ai eu un mal fou à décider entre les deux réponses et je regrette de ne pouvoir accepter les deux! J'accepte celui-ci car je pense que *Est modus in rebus* est la source, et c'est celui qui avait le plus de rapport avec la question d'origine sur ELU.

Comment: Par ailleurs, la remarque comme quoi il existe des extrêmes souhaitables cadre parfaitement avec la possibilité que la "bonne" maxime soit effectivement par rapport à "l'excès" plutôt que par rapport à "l'extrême".

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Pope, dans son *Essay on criticism* a écrit :

> Avoid extremes; and shun the fault of such,
>   Who still are pleased too little or too much.
>   At every trifle scorn to take offence:
>   That always shows great pride, or little sense:
>   Those heads, as stomachs, are not sure the best,
>   Which nauseate all, and nothing can digest.
>   Yet let not each gay turn thy rapture move;
>   For fools admire, but men of sense approve:
>   As things seem large which we through mist descry,
>   Dullness is ever apt to magnify.

Extrait traduit en prose française par M. J. Motheré dans une publication de 1881, comme suit :

> **Fuyez les extrêmes**, évitez le travers de ceux qu’on voit toujours trop ou trop peu satisfaits. Dédaignez de prendre ombrage pour la moindre vétille, marque infaillible d’un grand orgueil ou d’un petit sens : les meilleurs esprits comme les meilleurs estomacs, ne sont pas assurément ceux qui rejettent tout et ne saurait rien digérer. Mais n’allez pas éclater en transports pour le moindre tour brillant : car les sots admirent, mais l’homme de sens approuve : de même que les objets vus à travers la brume nous paraissent plus grands, ainsi la sottise tend à grossir toute chose.

Rien trouvé concernant « tout extrême nuit », mais cette considération philosophique sur la chasse, tirée des *Principes fondamentaux de la science forestière* de Henri Cotta, publiés en 1841 utilise « tout extrême est nuisible » :

> **Tout extrême est nuisible** ; et quel bien ne devient pas préjudiciable par l’abus ? Nous devons donc nous garder de dépasser les bornes du permis, et user de la chasse en ce qu’elle a de bon.

Je doute cependant que cet extrait soit à la source de la réminiscence invoquée dans la question.

Comment: J'ai eu un mal fou à décider entre les deux réponses et je regrette de ne pouvoir accepter les deux! Je pense que mon "Fuyez les extrêmes" vient effectivement de Pope.